# Flutter Image Custom Shape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image

How I can create a shape for the image? I need a shape for my image like this;

[image]

Tried with Container border but I can't manage the borders like this. How can I change my image's border like simple image?

Comment: You'll need to use a custom-painter for this

Answer (score 0):

try using this custom shape tool, [fluttershapemaker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/)

Comment: I tried but it's not solved my problem. I drew the shape but it's not affected my image.